# Rename, Delete Nodes in the Treeview using webforms

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, treeview

In the TreeView Control in web forms, need to right Click on the TreeView Node and Rename, Delete as if we do in winforms, is there any possible options for it. I even tried with javascript and RightClick event, i could fetch only the text and not the value of the node.

```
function RightClick(event) {
            var obj = event.srcElement || event.target;           
           var seltreeNode = obj;
           alert(seltreeNode.innerHTML); //This will prompt selected Node Text         
            var name = prompt("Enter New Name", seltreeNode.innerHTML);
            if (name != null && name != "") 
             {
                seltreeNode.innerHTML = name;
             }
                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Answer

```
 function GetSelectedNodeVal(event) 
      {
           var MailMessage_Control =  window.document.getElementById("TreeView").value;
           var treeViewData = window[MailMessage_Control + "_Data"]; 
           if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "")
           {   
                var obj = event.srcElement || event.target;
                var seltreeNode = obj;
                var name = prompt("Enter New Name", seltreeNode.innerHTML);
                if (name != null && name != "") 
                {
                    seltreeNode.innerHTML = name;
                }
                var NodeVal = window.document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
                var text = NodeVal.innerHTML;
                var value = NodeVal.href.substring(NodeVal.href.indexOf(",") + 3, NodeVal.href.length - 2);
                alert(name);
                alert(text);  
                alert(value);
                return true;
            }
            else
            { 
               alert("No node selected.");
               return false;
            }
     }
```